# String resources within build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Does anyone know if its possible to access string resources within the build.gradle file? something like the following.

```
dependencies {
   compile(group: 'com.mysite.myapp', name: 'lib', version: '@string/version_number', ext: 'aar')
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You'd rather do it the other way around (generate Android String resources based on information in the build script).

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work. Since it internally uses groovy.

```
def your_string = 'some_string';
dependencies {
   compile(group: 'com.mysite.myapp', name: 'lib', version: your_string + '/version_number', ext: 'aar')
}
```